# Why the Fermi energy be approximated as the chemical potential at low temperature?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, chemical-potential, fermi-energy

For the Fermi-Dirac distribution, $n(E)=\frac{1}{e^{\beta(E-\mu)}+1}$, why can we approximate the chemical potential, $\mu$, to be equal to the Fermi energy, $E_{f} = \mu(T=0) = k_{B} T_{f}$, when $T << T_{f}$?

Comment: What have you read that makes you think that it can? (I'm not saying it can't, just trying to figure out what direction a helpful answer would approach from.)

Comment: I had a homework problem where we found the Fermi temperature of a neutron star and were asked to explain if setting the temperature to be zero in the Fermi-Dirac distribution was a good approximation for finding the radius of the star by minimizing the total energy of the star (fermi gas energy plus gravitational potential energy). The answer was because $T << T_{f}$, we can set $\mu=k_{B}T_{f}$ and thus Fermi-Dirac distribution would be fairly close to the step function obtained when $T = 0$